# Opening url retrieved with PHP inside Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Need to open $link with javascript, that is retrieved from an XML file using PHP. Here's the code:

```
<?php

$url = "map.xml" ;
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$link = $xml->url[mt_rand(0,count($xml->url)-1)]->loc ; // Get Random Location 
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      window.open($link, "_blank"); // will open new tab on document ready
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access php variables from javascript. With php you can render html and javascript on server. So you need to print your  `$link` variable to the page:

```
window.open("<?= $link ?>", "_blank");
```

Note that short echo tag `<?=` is only guaranteed to be available on php 5.4+, if you are stuck supporting an older version use `<?php echo` instead

Comment: Ah, fantastic. Thank you! That worked (not sure why I overlooked the obvious). cheers

Comment: Because it's a language feature that makes things easier. And it's good coding style to make use of language features as much as you can.